# Codeigniter how to access views/web pages from third party folders

Tags: php, codeigniter, simplesamlphp

I am in the process of installing SimpleSAML and in the php library, there is a folder called www that has index.php. According to the docs, there is an admin console within it. However, at the moment I am unable to access it via the url www.website.com/third_party/simplesaml/www/index.php.

I am supposed to use the admin console to generate some metadata so I'm just wondering if it is possible to route to a view from there?

I'm thinking that I create a controller and just hard link $this->load->view('url to www') but I'm not sure if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller’s constructor add

include APPPATH . 'third_party/simplesaml/www/index.php';

to include the file in your project.

Comment: Thanks for replying! How do I access that index then?

Comment: Refer this link  https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-third-party-libraries-folder/

Comment: I read that. There is nothing to call like that third party folder. I just need the view. Do I just do $this->load->view(index.php)?

Answer (score 0):

you can set base path in route file and instead of $this->load->view() you can use renderView() function to access view in codeigniter.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I'll try this.

Comment: Hello, how do I use this?

Comment: $this->template->renderView('index','CryptoCurrency/index',$params);that's how you can access view from controller.

Comment: here template is a class in which you have to make renderView().just try to get an idea about user define template class in codeigniter from google then implement it.